# how to monitor the status of Celery task

Tags: python, django, celery

I want to monitor the status of a celery task.

for example: 
I have a celery task that read that reads a table every minute, when the task is executed at minute 2 I do not want to read what I already read the first task

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
'add-every-1-minute': {
    'task': 'read_data_base',
    'schedule': 1.0
}
```

}

Comment: This is an English language site. Please ask in that language, or ask at [Stack Overflow en español](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) instead.

Comment: Por favor, publique sus preguntas en inglés en Stack Overflow. Si desea publicar en español, intente https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: This post is like an exotic Spanish recipe for downvotes.

Comment: @JacobH What downvotes? Just because a question is in another language doesn't mean it isn't a good one.

Comment: Porque no es Inglés? Tambien, estoy jugando.